# webpackJsonp is not defined: webpack-dev-server and CommonsChunkPlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, commonschunkplugin

This is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  cache: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    app : [
      './src/index.js'
    ],
    vendor: ['lodash']
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    pathinfo: true
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel'] },
      { test: /\.scss/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass'] }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.bundle.js', Infinity)
  ]
};
```

And this is my scripts that runs the webpack-dev-server:

```
const webpack =require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const webpackConfig = require('../webpack.config');
const _  = require('lodash');

const webpackDevConfig = _.cloneDeep(webpackConfig);
const devPort = 3000;

webpackDevConfig.entry.app.unshift('webpack/hot/dev-server');
webpackDevConfig.entry.app.unshift('webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:' + devPort + '/');
webpackDevConfig.plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(webpackDevConfig), {
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    chunks: false
  }
}).listen(devPort, 'localhost');
```

The `webpack` command output is good (bundle.js and vendor.bundle.js), however, the dev server fails with `webpackJsonp is not defined` (although its in-memory compilation succeeded).

When removing `CommonsChunkPlugin` from webpack.config.js - it all works fine:

```
...
entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
...
plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you find a solution ?

Answer (score 15):

In your *index.html* file just call *vendor.bundle.js* before *bundle.js*

```
<script src="assets/js/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

That's all, now it should work. [More information.](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/606)

Answer (score 1):

Rename vendor entry point to

'vendor.js': ['lodash']

Comment: It didn't work. I tried it already when I saw https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/368. I also tried it with passing an object to commonschunkplugin plugin (instead of 3 params...) and it didn't work as well... :(

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand a little on the concept, the vendor has to come first since the runtime is contained in there (everything that defines all the variables and methods run during client load time because of all the webpacking).

If you use a manifest file (because of chunking and so on), you'll have to put that first since it will then contain the runtime because of the way the module is built.