# Reference error: WebpackJsonp not defined

Tags: angularjs, electron

Converted my existing Angular 2 project into electron base cross platform than I installed [electron-forge start](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge)  development tools for development to simple easy way to package.

A command to launch app : **electron-forge start**

Unlikely returned an reference error **"WebpackJsonp not defined"** in error popup.

I found one of [Stackoverflow answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39322819/1339473) to put your vendor.js before main.js but unfortunately it's not work in my case.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist/main.bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "build": "ng build --base-href $npm_package_config_baseurl",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.62",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "electron-compile": "^6.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.3",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.7.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "1.6.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  },
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "make_targets": {
        "win32": [
          "squirrel"
        ],
        "darwin": [
          "zip"
        ],
        "linux": [
          "deb",
          "rpm"
        ]
      },
      "electronPackagerConfig": {},
      "electronWinstallerConfig": {
        "name": ""
      },
      "electronInstallerDebian": {},
      "electronInstallerRedhat": {},
      "github_repository": {
        "owner": "",
        "name": ""
      },
      "windowsStoreConfig": {
        "packageName": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone face this issue before ? What would be a possible case of this error ? 
 Your help would highly appreciate . Thanks in advance.